# Access TFS in another domain

Tags: tfs

I need to access TFS outside the domain. I thought that I can publish the TFS through WAP, but it seems that TFS does not support the authentication used by ADFS. Any other idea on how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

TFS does not support ADFS, there is a [user voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/6536517-implement-ad-fs-for-tfs) here, you can go and vote it up or summit a new user voice to achieve it in future.

However, to access TFS outside the domain you can try below items:

- Try to provide access to TFS over a virtual private network (VPN).
- Try to provide access to TFS through a reverse proxy such as Microsoft Internet Security and Acceleration (ISA) Server.
- Try to host your TFS server on an extranet.

You can reference this article : [Providing Internet Access to Team Foundation Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668967.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Besides, you can use **Visual Studio Online**, connecting remotely is a good option. And if you are doing any cloud work it integrates nicely.

This link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252507(v=vs.100).aspx) from Microsoft describes various domain \ work group combos for your reference.

Comment: @user3616544 Have you resolved your issue by above suggestion? any update?